# iPhone: add an image to grouped uitableview section header?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, header

I know I can change the way the section header looks by implementing `viewForHeaderInSection:`

The thing is I want to add a UIImageView to the right of the header text without modifying the look of the already existing label.

I can create my own view and add a UILabel and a UIImageView, but then, I'd have to setup the label color and font to match the standard look

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to create your own view holder, image, and label, and try to match the standard look. Sorry!

Comment: do you have any idea what's the default text color of the section header label?

Comment: You'll have to experiment. I recommend taking a look at xScope; it'll let you examine the colors in the sim.