# "mini-map" in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mapkit

How can I add a "mini-map" in my `UITableViewController`?

I would like to use the same "design/layout" as with Maps app. Please see:

[image]

Comment: Have a look to this answer [add an image to grouped uitableview section header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068878/iphone-add-an-image-to-grouped-uitableview-section-header/2068978#2068978)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain the border around the map. My first guess would be that the map is a UIButton with the map as view, but as far as I can recall, the MKMapView is not a subclass of UIView and therefore cannot be set as the subview of an UIButton... right?

Comment: `The map is a UIButton with the map as view` that seem more possible, you are right

Comment: Yet I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @paul-peelen Check out my answer for you how you could have this as a subview of a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your example in the question is achieved with `UITableView header view`. Try dragging a `UIView` to you `UITableView Controller`, and customize that `UIView`. It should be much easier than modifying a `TableViewCell`.

Reference:

[UITableView Header (not section header) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442171/uitableview-header-not-section-header-problem)

Comment: Well, my UITableViewController is done by code, not with IB. So I can't drag it. I solved it now creating a custom UITableViewCell wich has a UIButton and a UILabel (almost as you suggested).

Comment: @Paul Peelen You can also add a new UIView to the Controller with only code.

Answer (score 10):

You might consider, rather than having a fully functional MKMapView in your UI, use the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). You can just format a URL with the appropriate location and get back an image asynchronously. You can stick the results in a [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=kakn%C3%A4stornet&size=88x88&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false
```

[image: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=kakn%C3%A4stornet&size=88x88&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false]

Just make sure you cache the results, so you aren't hitting Google servers every time someone runs your app.

Here is a URL with a [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers) included:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=kakn%C3%A4stornet&size=88x88&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:tiny|color:green|kakn%C3%A4stornet&sensor=false
```

[image]

Comment: Niceone, didn't know about that. Can one add an annotation pin to it?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, or at least almost. Thanks to @AhmadTK.

This is my code:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "RackAnnotation.h"

#import <QuartzCore/CATransaction.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>

[...]

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        [cell.textLabel setText:theAnnotationSet._address];

        [cell.textLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];

        MKMapView *mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 68, 68)];
        mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
        mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
        [mapView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottomRight];

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center=theAnnotationSet._coordinate;

        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
        region.span=span;

        [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
        [mapView addAnnotation:theAnnotationSet];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

        UIButton *mapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
        [mapButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        CALayer *mapLayer = mapView.layer;
        mapLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        mapLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

        [mapButton addSubview:mapView];
        [mapButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];

        CALayer *layer = mapButton.layer;
        layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

        [cell addSubview:mapButton];
        [cell setAccessoryView:mapButton];
        [cell setEditing:YES];

        NSLog(@"Title: %@", theAnnotationSet._address);

        return cell;

    }
    else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }


        return cell;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The only problem I have left is getting it on the left side. As far as I can see that can only be done by using your own subclass and either UITableViewCell or set your own view as header.

The other thing I have left to figure out is how to remove "Googl" in this mini-map. I mean, I have it in the main map and now its just annoying me.

Cheers,
Paul Peelen

Comment: If you plan to submit this to the app store, don't remove the Googl from the map. It's required by the license agreement that it not be obscured.  You might even get dinged for not showing the whole name.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Read it in the agreement. But I figured since google themselfs don't show it on the details page and since it represents a position on the map that has been selected on a large map which does contain "Google" I thought they might approve it anyways. But, how would I remove it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to remove it; I found out all this because I wanted to put a button on the lower left corner of a map, and it covered "Google".

Comment: I understand. I might just expand it a litte bit. I updated my app now with an own UITableViewCell with the button on the left side. Cheated a bit and did most of it in IB.. ;)

Comment: You could probably make the map view's frame bigger and clip it by putting it as a subview inside another (smaller) view.

Comment: @PaulPeelen Checkout the static map approach I posted. The google logo comes back scaled for static map image requests.